# Is there a way to print 2 textes with different font sizes? C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I would like to print 2 textes, but with different size

now I'm using this code to change the font size, it works but if I want a text bigger I can't.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "user32")

HANDLE out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

void fontsize(int a, int b) {

    PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX lpConsoleCurrentFontEx = new CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX();
    lpConsoleCurrentFontEx->cbSize = sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX);
    GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(out, 0, lpConsoleCurrentFontEx);
    lpConsoleCurrentFontEx->dwFontSize.X = a;
    lpConsoleCurrentFontEx->dwFontSize.Y = b;
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(out, 0, lpConsoleCurrentFontEx);
}

void main() {


    fontsize(12, 16);
    cout << "text" << endl;


    system("pause");
}
```

so imagine I have 2 textes, textA and textB.
I want textB bigger than textA.

Comment: What makes you think that the console supports drawing text in multiple sizes (simultaneously)?

Comment: I don't know, I'm just asking if it's possible

Comment: A console only has one font in one size, so no, you can't use different sizes.

Comment: You have a leak with the unnecessary `new` operator. Just declare `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX info = {0};` and pass `&info` in to relevant function.